# When dynamically adding I2C device through sysfs. Is it possible to also define the GPIO pins that comes with the I2C device?

Tags: linux, drivers, devices

I have two I2C devices I want to connect to my Linux device. A temperature sensor, TMP117, worked fine by writing it to the `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-x/new_device`. In addition, I want to add an accelerometer, ADXL343. However, when using the same method as with the TMP117, I receive an error in `dmesg` that the GPIO for the interrupt is not found. This also affects a GPIO extender, which requires the interrupt signal for my application.

Is it possible to dynamically add I2C devices with additional signals, such as interrupts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices follows, that you can *only* pass an I²C address as parameter. So, how would the kernel know on which GPIO line that interrupt line is connected?

So, complex drivers that encompass more hardware than just an I²C device cannot be used this way.

The "correct" way would probably writing a devicetree entry (1b from above document) if you know where the hardware sits at boot time (or even if you don't – nowadays, you can modify the devicetree at runtime). If that's not an option, you'd need to write a kernel module.

**However, good news**: Michael Hennerich of ADI (nice guy, buy him a coffee if you meet him) has written the [`adxl34x` driver](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/input-misc/adxl345#driver_compiled_as_a_module) (included in upstream linux), so this really just boils down to telling your kernel (again, via devicetree) at which address to find your ADXL34x on the I²C bus, and on which interrupt lines to listen to.

Comment: Thanks, it's an intel platform, so it is using ACPI. Adding the device to the ACPI namespace is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: read the document I linked to – it has a section about ACPI, which refers you to specific documentation on how to do it on ACPI.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read, [Linux offers 4 methods for instantiating I2C devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices).

Since the sysfs interface offers only 2 attribute files (`new_device` and `delete_device`) and the `new_device` takes 2 parameters only (the name of the I2C device and the address of the I2C device), I am afraid that you just cannot fiddle the IRQ from userland.

However, since the  [i2c_board_info structure](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/i2c.html#c.i2c_board_info) makes provision for some IRQ setting I suggest you prefer declaring the I2C device by bus number as described in *Method 1a* (cf first link) enabling you to precisely define the structure like in the example given:

```
static struct i2c_board_info h4_i2c_board_info[] __initdata = {
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("isp1301_omap", 0x2d),
        .irq        = OMAP_GPIO_IRQ(125),
    },
...
};
```

Comment: Okay, so if I understand this correctly:

1. I create a `i2c_board_info` struct containing the information for my device.
2. I pass this struct into the `i2c_new_client_device` [function](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/i2c.html#c.i2c_new_client_device).

Would I then be able to compile and run this program? And then the device should be available to me?